# Can you still map a network drive from Explorer?

Tags: windows-10

I already know you can map network drives from right-clicking "This PC" but I am sure in older versions of Windows you could do so from an Explorer window after navigating to the network folder you wanted to map? If so is this still possible in Windows 10?

e.g. you navigate to \OtherPC\Folder123 and then find a menu option "map this folder to network drive"?

Can anyone confirm if this *did* use to be how it worked in older versions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At least in Windows 10.20H2, this button appears to have been stuffed into the "Easy access" menu-button along with other network-related options:

[image: Screenshot of Explorer showing the menu item]

The same option is also still available when right-clicking on the shared folder itself, while navigated to `\\server`.

Comment: So... they moved it to an item named "Easy access" that's more difficult to access? Sounds about right.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- You have to click "Start" to "Shut down".

Comment: @Ray, Since you're not immediately Shutting Down the computer, but actually Starting a process that finishes with the computer shutting down, then it does make sense from a certain point of view.

Comment: @CitizenRon It's AFAIK not starting a process but calling a WinAPI function (one of https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/system-shutdown-functions), but don't worry about that as my comment is just a citation of a decade old joke used when trying to mock Windows :P

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- You've succinctly summed up the Windows 10 UI/UX model.

Answer (score -2):

Open Windows Explorer, From navigation (left pane) click "This PC" (unless you have set explorer to open there

[image]

Then from Computer tab click "Map Network drive"

[image]

Then follow the wizard

[image]

At least True on Windows 10 (2004)

Comment: The question explicitly asks if you can map the currently open directory, which implies that they want to avoid having to enter a path in the wizard.